# Are there any good tutorial about using buildout and pip?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, buildout

I've been struggling all day to really understand how to use buildout and pip.
Watched a bunch of videos etc., but I still have a hard time figuring out the do and don't of buildout and pip.

Any help, tutorial, book is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is not the http://www.buildout.org/ and http://pip.openplans.org/ tutorials helpful? Apart from that, there are couple of tutorials on Buildout[1](http://grok.zope.org/documentation/tutorial/introduction-to-zc.buildout), PIP [2](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip) which could be helpful for you to start.

Best way to start, write a small buildout conf and using an existing recipe from PyPI and see how the package installs.

Comment: thanks for the links. Spent the whole day googling around. Very helpful.

Comment: The actual buildout tutorial isn't a tutorial at all. It's a slightly more elaborate version of the handout to a presentation. It actually reads much like a transcript rather than a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: it looks like http://buildout.org is out of date, or at least the doc is about zc.buildout 1.2. am I mistaken?

Comment: @ErikAllik - Possibly. This was answered last year.